# How to make a change to a file in wp-includes?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the Hestia theme. I created a child theme for Hestia.

**Hestia theme**

wp-content/themes/hestia

**Child Theme**

wp-content/themes/hestia-child

**I need to make a change in the file *wp-includes/general-template.php***

**How Can I make the change below without directly altering the file from wp-includes?**

wp-content/themes/hestia/archive.php

```
<?php the_archive_title( '<h1 class="hestia-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
```

wp-includes/general-template.php

```
// This function calls get_the_archive_title
function the_archive_title( $before = '', $after = '' ) {
    $title = get_the_archive_title();

    if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
        echo $before . $title . $after;
    }
}

// Original
function get_the_archive_title() {
    if ( is_author() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( 'Author: %s' ), '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' );
    } 
}

// What I need to change - 'Author: %s' to '%s'
function get_the_archive_title() {
    if ( is_author() ) {   
        $title = sprintf( __( '%s' ), '<span class="vcard">' .get_the_author() . '</span>' );
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want to change ?

Comment: In the get_the_archive_title() I change 'Author: %s' to '%s' BUT the thing is this function is in the wp-includes folder so I don't want to make the change directly from that file

Comment: [click here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175884/how-to-customize-the-archive-title) is your answer to customize the output of get_the_archive_title

Answer (score 0):

Some "filter" and "hook" putting this in your functions.php :
Please check below reference link.

Link1 :- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60605/function-to-change-a-label-username-in-a-core-wordpress-file-wp-includes-gene/60607?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Link2 :- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255677/how-to-modify-files-inside-wp-includes-directory-in-wordpress?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ( $title ) {

    if( is_category() ) {

        $title = single_cat_title( '', false );

    }

    return $title;

});
```